# Does HTC opensense SDK work only on android devices with HTC Sense?

Tags: android, htc-android

Recently I just discovered the HTC opensense SDK.

Will this SDK only work on HTC devices, or devices with HTC Sense installed, or will it work on other devices?

Link: http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk

Has anyone used this SDK before?

Answer (score 1):

There's a showcase of some of the successful third party apps at the bottom of this page that use the SDK:
http://htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk

The functionality of the SDK only works on HTC devices in general, although sometimes a library is included to help aid development on emulators like with the Scribe active pen API. We do recommend that you write apps as a single APK that works on all devices, however, be they HTC or otherwise.

You can do this by targeting the SDK just like you would target a high version of Android, then checking using reflection or other methods when to use the extra functions. This is the same approach most developers use for supporting features only introduced in newer versions of Android. You can also have an Android library project that targets the SDK and a main project that targets something else if needed, and still produce a single APK.

You can see an example of the first technique in the samples directory of the add on. That's android-sdk\add-ons\addon-opensense_sdk_for_tablets-htc-12\samples where android-sdk is where you installed the SDK and you have the current OpenSense SDK installed from the Google SDK Manager. The sample project name for that is SingleApkDemo. The name of the add on will probably change in the next release but we'll still have samples in the directory.

Comment: The only thing i need from the opensense sdk is the tablplus. Which seems to be a tabhost but with some improved ui effects. Would it be possible to find source for the tabplus in the sdk ?